# Query data from a PostgreSQL dump

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a dump that was made from a PostgreSQL database. I want to check for some information in that dump, specifically checking if there are entries in a certain table with certain values in certain fields.

This is for a Python program that should run automatically on many different inputs on customer machines, so I need a programmatic solution, not manually opening the file and looking for where that table is defined. I could restore the dump to a database and then delete it, but I'm worrying that this operation is heavy or that it has side-effects. I want there to be no side-effects to my query, I just want to do the check without it affecting anything in my system.

Is that possible in any way? Preferably in Python?

Comment: If each table is it's own dump file, you can use grep, awk or regular expressions insde python otherwise there's no easy way

Comment: 1) there are *at least* three different formats for pg_dump. 2) pg_restore knows about these. 3) you *could* try to emulate `pg_restore... | psql ...`, or use `pg_restore ...|grep ...` for simple cases. 4) or just restore into a (temporary) database and work from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Any dump format: restore and query

The most practical thing to do is restore them to a temporary PostgreSQL database then query the database. It's by far the simplest option. If you have a non-superuser with `createdb` rights you can do this pretty trivially and safely with `pg_restore`.

### SQL-format

If it's a plaintext (.sql) format dump, if desperate and you know the dumps were *not* created with the `--inserts` or `--column-inserts` options and you don't use the same table name in multiple schemas, you could just search for the text

```
COPY tablename (
```

at the start of a line, then read the `COPY`-format data (see below) until you find `\.` at the start of a line.

If you *do* use the same table name in different schemas you have to parse the dump to find the `SET search_path` entry for the schema you want, then start looking for the desired table `COPY` statement.

### Custom-format

However, if the dump is in the [PostgreSQL custom format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html), which you should always prefer and request by using `-Fc` with `pg_dump`, it is IIRC really a tar file with a custom header. You can either seek within it to find the tar header then extract it, or you can use `pg_restore` to list its header and then extract individual tables.

For this task I'd do the latter. To list tables in the dump:

```
pg_restore --list out.dump
```

To dump a particular table as tab-separated `COPY` format by qualified name, e.g. table `address` in schema `public`:

```
pg_restore -n public -t address out.dump
```

The output has a bunch of stuff you can't get `pg_restore` to skip at the start, but your script can just look for the word `COPY` (uppercase) at the start of a line and start reading on the next line, until it reaches a `\.` at the end of a line. For details on the format see [the PostgreSQL manual on `COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

Of course you need the `pg_restore` binary for this.

---

Make sure there is no `PGDATABASE` environment variable set when you invoke `pg_restore`. Otherwise it'll restore to a DB instead of printing output to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Dump the database to a CSV file (or a CSV file for each table) and then you can load and query them using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/).

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your dump to INSERT INTO dump with this little tool I've written :

https://github.com/freddez/pg-dump2insert

It will be easier to grep specific table data in this form.